# An interesting darts problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory

I've stumbled across what I believe to be an interesting result - feel free to argue that it isn't!

Say we simplify the game of darts such that we only play with two darts. Then, according to my calculations, there are $1323$ possible ways to 'checkout' (finish on a double), the lowest being $2$ (Double $1$), the highest being $110$ (Treble $20$ + bullseye).

Interestingly (or not!), there are exactly $882$ possible ways to checkout from the even numbers: $2,4,6,...,110$; and $441$ possible ways to checkout from the odd numbers: $3,5,7,...,107$ ($107$ is the maximum odd number checkout). Therefore there are exactly twice as many ways to checkout from the even numbers when compared to the odd numbers.

A coincidence?

Probably worth mentioning that this trend vanishes when you extend to the full three dart version of the game: $82047$ ($45444$ even + $36603$ odd).

Comment: I know nothing about darts, but my guess is that this is not a coincidence. Perhaps given an odd number from which you might check out there are two particular ways to reach an even number from which you do. OK that sentence might be darts nonsense. But I would look for some kind of one-to-two mapping connecting checkouts from odds to checkouts from evens.

Comment: I'm assuming you're playing straight in and doubling out, and on a double bullseye.  Then, for the peanut gallery, any individual dart can score any of the following numbers: $0$ (misses the board), $1$ through $20$, double $1$ through $20$ (which obviously overlaps some of the previous range), triple $1$ through $20$ (ditto), $25$ (single bullseye), or $50$ (double bullseye).  The last dart to hit the board must "check out" or "double out": It must be a double $1$ through $20$, or double bullseye.

Comment: OP, is that all basically correct?  Please feel free to fix any misconceptions I had.  ETA: There may not be a single bullseye.  You should probably clarify that one way or the other.

Comment: I dont think I understand the latest comments...  How can I possibly check out from an odd number, if I miss one of the 2 darts?  The other dart must score even (to check out) and yet I begin with an odd number.

Comment: Also pls clarify: do (2x9, 2x8) and (2x8, 2x9) count as two different ways to checkout from 34, or does that count as one way?

Comment: OK so no. of ways to check out an odd number = |odd scores| x |doubles| = 21 x 21 = 441.  But no. of ways to check out an even number = |even scores| x |doubles| = 41 x 21 = 861, which is not twice 441.  How did you get 882?  What am i missing?

Comment: OK, here goes again...

Brian, exactly correct. Although I didn't include misses! If you do the nice result is lost: total = 1323+21=1344, even = 882+21=903, odd = 441. Thanks for clarifying this antkam (I had a brain fade before!). Yes, that would be two different ways.
If misses are not considered:
odd scores x doubles = 21 x 21 = 441
even scores x doubles + hitting the double straight off = 41 x 21 + 21 = 882 
If misses are considered:
odd scores x doubles = 441
even scores x doubles + hitting the double straight off + missing the double then hitting it = 41 x 21 + 21 + 21 = 903